# Show yearly X labels for June instead of January on d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a line chart in d3.js where I have labels on the X-axis every year (showing 20 years of data). The labels are created with:

```
g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b/%d/%Y")).ticks(d3.timeYear))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dy", ".25em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");
```

The outcome looks like this:

[image: X-axis]

Now, the thing is, I need the labels to not be placed on January 1st of each year - I need them on June 30th. How can I accomplish that?

See the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1bvrd50/) here to try for yourself.

Comment: Can you create a codepen/jsfiddle/codesandbox to play with? I have done this previously with regular scales (not time) using a `filter` and `remove` or `hide`.

Comment: @Coola Added a fiddle at the end of the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to specify explicitly each desired axis tick's value. The function [`axis.tickValues`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues) is designed for this.

The following function generates an array of dates, starting from the `min` date (june 28th, 2000 in your case), and adding a year until the `max` date (june 28th, 2020) is reached. It is necessary to go through this generation step because the dataset does not contain data for all years.

```
    function generateTickvalues(min, max) {
        let res = []
        , currentExtent = new Date(min.valueOf())

        while(currentExtent <= max) {
            res.push(new Date(currentExtent.valueOf()))
            currentExtent.setFullYear(currentExtent.getFullYear() + 1);
        }

      return res

    }
```

Remark: `new Date(date.valueOf())` is necessary in this function so that the date values from the original dataset are not overwritten.

The min and max dates from the dataset can conveniently be found using [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#extent). This array can also be used when calling `x.domain`.

```
let dateExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date})

let tickValues = generateTickvalues(dateExtent[0], dateExtent[1])

x.domain(dateExtent);
```

Then, when generating the axis, call the function `axis.tickValues`, passing the array of years starting from June just generated:

```
d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b/%d/%Y"))
  .ticks(d3.timeYear)
  .tickValues(tickValues)
```

Demo in the snippet below:

```js
const data = [
    { value: 46, date: '2000-06-28', formatted_date: '06/28/2000' },
    { value: 48, date: '2003-06-28', formatted_date: '06/28/2003' },
    { value: 26, date: '2004-06-28', formatted_date: '06/28/2004' },
    { value: 36, date: '2006-06-28', formatted_date: '06/28/2006' },
    { value: 40, date: '2010-06-28', formatted_date: '06/28/2010' },
    { value: 48, date: '2012-06-28', formatted_date: '06/28/2012' },
    { value: 34, date: '2018-06-28', formatted_date: '06/28/2018' },
    { value: 33, date: '2020-06-28', formatted_date: '06/28/2020' }
  ];
  
  create_area_chart(data, 'history-chart-main');
  
  function generateTickvalues(min, max) {
      let res = []
        , currentExtent = new Date(min.valueOf())

        while(currentExtent <= max) {
          res.push(new Date(currentExtent.valueOf()))
          currentExtent.setFullYear(currentExtent.getFullYear() + 1);
        }

      return res

  }
  
  function create_area_chart(data, target){
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = '';
    var parentw = document.getElementById(target).offsetWidth;
    var parenth = 0.6*parentw;
    var svg = d3.select('#'+target).append("svg").attr("width", parentw).attr("height", parenth),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 40, left: 50},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
    bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var area = d3.area()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y1(function (d) { return y(d.value); });

    data.forEach(function (d) {
        //only parse time if not already parsed (i.e. when using time period filters)
        if(parseTime(d.date))
            d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    let dateExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date})
    
    
    let tickValues = generateTickvalues(dateExtent[0], dateExtent[1])
 
  x.domain(dateExtent);
    
    y.domain([0, 1.05 * d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })]);
    area.y0(y(0));

    g.append("rect")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + -margin.left + "," + -margin.top + ")")
        .attr("width", svg.attr("width"))
        .attr('class', 'overlay')
        .attr("height", svg.attr("height"))
        .on("mouseover", function () {
            d3.selectAll(".eps-tooltip").remove();
            d3.selectAll(".eps-remove-trigger").remove();
            focus.style("display", "none");
        });

    g.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "#f6f6f6")
        .attr("d", area);

    //create line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function (d) { return y(d.value); });

    g.append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', '#068d46')
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b/%d/%Y")).ticks(d3.timeYear).tickValues(tickValues))
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

    g.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
            .tickFormat(function (d) { return "$" + d }))
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#068d46")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");

    var focus = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "focus")
        .style("display", "none");

    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "x-hover-line hover-line")
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height);

    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "y-hover-line hover-line")
        .attr("x1", width)
        .attr("x2", width);

    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("fill", "#068d46")
        .attr("r", 4);

    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "text-date focus-text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle");

    focus.append("text")
        .attr("class", "text-val focus-text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", -30)
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle");

    g.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .on("mouseover", function () { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mousemove", function () {
            var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
                    i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
                    d0 = data[i - 1],
                    d1 = data[i],
                    d = x0 - d0.year > d1.year - x0 ? d1 : d0;
            focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
            focus.select(".text-date").text(function () { return d.formatted_date; });
            focus.select(".text-val").text(function () { return '$' + d.value; });
            focus.select(".x-hover-line").attr("y2", height - y(d.value));
            focus.select(".y-hover-line").attr("x2", width + width);
        });
}
```

```css
.chart {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 10px 25px 10px;
    background: #f6f6f6;
  }

  .chart svg {
    overflow: visible;
  }

  .chart .overlay {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart" id="history-chart-main"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works if the dataset starts with June 28th. Perhaps my example dataset wasn't perfect, but there could be data points on different dates - we still need to use June 28th for the ticks though. Could you offer a suggestion on how to modify the solution for this case?

Comment: If you have a date `min`, and want to modify it to June 28th in the same year, use the following: `new Date(new Date(min.setMonth(5)).setDate(28))`

Comment: I've already accepted your answer, but I have an issue with this: for some reason, it freezes the whole browser when I try to set the date. Setting the month is fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any error in the console when you leave the script running? Does it happen in any specific browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an interval with `axis.ticks()`, D3 provides a number of built in intervals which we can use and then filter for the appropriate day/month/time.

If we wanted June 1 every year we could use:

```
var axis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b/%d/%Y"))
    .ticks(d3.timeMonth.filter(function(d) { return d.getMonth() == 5; })))
```

If we want June 30 we can specify with a bit more specificity:

```
 var axis = d3.axisBottom(x)
   .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b/%d/%Y"))
   .ticks(d3.timeDay.filter(function(d) { return d.getMonth() == 5 && d.getDate() == 30 }))
```

The d3-time [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-time) have some more description of d3 intervals and the d3-scale documentation time scale details have some example implementations of this method [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time_ticks).

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0tegqan/)

Comment: This works, but when I do the d.getDate check it freezes the whole application for like a minute. Perhaps this can be replaced with something less demanding? The date is always the last of the month (so if June, it's always 30).

Comment: Hmm, I didn't get the delay, but let me take another look.